# Rails active_admin put data from javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My active_admin links.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Link do

column :category do |c|

       collection_select(:link, :category, Category.all, :category_id, :category_name,{:selected => c.category},{:class => "custom_title", :id=>c.id } )


  end
```

My JS:

```
$('.custom_title').change(function (){



        var a = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url:    "admin_links", 
                data: { links:{ category:a} }
              });

    });
```

Select change but what should i write in active_admin links.rb to get this data from JS and update database with choosen option from select? What i want is "auto" update database on select change.